# Where can I download SharePoint Foundation 2010 without SP2

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

I need to set up a development environment for a site that is currently running SP1. I set up my dev environment with SP2010 SP2 and then I found out the hard way that you cannot restore a backup from an older version onto a newer version. Upgrading the production site to SP2 is an option but that needs to be scheduled and tested and might be a month or two out. I would like to be able to develop in the mean time. Is there any way to downgrade my SP 2010 foundation SP2 to SP1, or is there an installer that has just the base SP Foundation 2010 or SP Foundation 2010 plus SP1? I can only find the one that includes SP2 updates on the Microsoft download web site.

Answer (score 3):

i think its too late to get the foundation with sp1. i checked the msdn but over there its already sp2. best option to contact MSFT and get the old bits from there.
That's why i always say, keep the copy of exe files until the product life.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link for downloading Sharepoint foundation 2010 SP1 http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=26640

Comment: This is just the Service Pack, no use without a SharePoint installation without any SP:s applied